# .Net Core 2.1 Web API using JWT and JWT Cookie at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to store the JWT in a cookie and use it to authenticate the user OR the bearer token from the HTTP header.

At the moment I am using HTTP-Auth header only and it's working.

I tried using Identity Cookies and JwT like this:

```
[Authorize] //Cookie auth?!
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(...)

...

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
```

I also tried adding different Schemes in `AddAuthentication()`. It's not working.

**My Question is how to activate JWT and ASP.NET Identity Authentication simultaneously for Actions/Controllers.**

Comment: What is the question? You got downvoted because as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your description I'm guessing you need more than one authentication on your actions.

You can add multiple Authentication Schema which you did with `AddJwtBearer` and `AddIdentity`, and on `AuthorizeAttribute` choose multiple schema.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + ", " + Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)]
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for. But this gives me an error: `An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type` I tried wrapping this up in a static readonly string. Doesn't work either; `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthType.Value)]`

Comment: Oh and I really wanted to know how to store the JWT in a cookie and use this for authorization + Normal Microsoft JWT Authorization. But combining Identity + JWT should be okay too, as long as both work simultaneously.

Comment: Changed it to `"Bearer, Identity.Application"` and it seems to work :) I just need a way to simplify it, so I don't have to put `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer, Identity.Application")]` above each Action/Controller. Any ideas?

Comment: @DoubleVoid here's one option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution